# query a column that does not have the same value in another column

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, self-join

My Table

```
ItemCode      ItemName       Total
----------------------------------
A              name1          5
A              name1          5
A              name2          10
B              name1          10 
B              name2          25
B              name1          30
C              name2          5
C              name1          30
C              name1          20
```

i want to display all `itemcode` `A` and `B` that does not have the same value in column `Total`

My expected Result

```
ItemCode          ItemName         Total
----------------------------------------
A                  name1             5
A                  name1             5
B                  name2             25
B                  name1             30
```

I already asked this question but this time my question is much clearer than my last quesiton. I think 1 solution for this is a self join but i cant figure it out. any help would mean a lot to me thanks!

Comment: Still not that clear to me: why the rows with ItemCode = 'A' in the expected result? they come from perfectly equal rows, with the same Total, while you say "does not have the same value in column Total". Do you mean that you only want the rows for which does not exist a row of a different ItemCode with the same Total?

Comment: @Aleksej Hi Aleksej thank you for helping me really. All i want is to get all itemname's in itemcode 'A' and 'B' that does not have the same `Total` but if they are in the same itemcode and have the same total i want them to be included.

Comment: Do you want only for pair A and B or for every pair like (A,C)  (B,C) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need the rows for which does not exist another row of a different `itemCode` with the same `Total`, and assuming that `ItemCode` is always not null, a simple solution can be this:

```
with test(ItemCode, ItemName, Total) as 
(
    select 'A', 'name1', 5  from dual union all
    select 'A', 'name1', 5  from dual union all
    select 'A', 'name2', 10 from dual union all
    select 'B', 'name1', 10 from dual union all
    select 'B', 'name2', 25 from dual union all
    select 'B', 'name1', 30 from dual union all
    select 'C', 'name2', 5  from dual union all
    select 'C', 'name1', 30 from dual union all
    select 'C', 'name1', 20 from dual
)
select *
from test t1
where ItemCode in ('A', 'B')
  and not exists (
                   select 1
                   from test t2
                   where t1.total    =  t2.total
                     and t1.itemCode != t2.itemCode
                     and ItemCode in ('A', 'B')
                 )
```

The following is faster, but less readable:

```
select ItemCode, ItemName, Total
from (
        select ItemCode, ItemName, Total, count(distinct ItemCode) over (partition by Total) as itemCount
        from test
        where ItemCode in ('A', 'B')
     )
where itemCount = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query:

```
select i.*
from my_table i
where i.ItemCode in ('A','B')
and (select count(*) from my_table t where t.ItemCode in ('A','B') 
and t.ItemCode != i.ItemCode and t.total = i.total) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.* FROM (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ITEMCODE='A')A
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ITEMCODE='B')B ON
    A.TOTAL=B.TOTAL
WHERE B.ITEMCODE IS NULL

UNION

SELECT B.* FROM (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ITEMCODE='B')B
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ITEMCODE='A')A ON
    B.TOTAL=A.TOTAL
WHERE A.ITEMCODE IS NULL
```